# How do I search all spaces not matching a non breaking space with a regular expression?

Tags: regex

I am trying to use a regex to change spaces (they can be x20 \t etc.) in certain strings  with a non-breaking space in a long text. But I want to avoid finding the strings where the replacement has been done already. I am using both Libreoffice's search and replace and the extension Alternative Find and Replace for writer v. 1.4.2

I've tried : (without the [])

```
Search [(cf|vgl)(\.)+(?<!xA0)(\s)+

Replace [$1$2 ]
```

My source of information is: https://unicode-org.github.io/icu/userguide/strings/regexp.html#regular-expression-operators

I hope someone can help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a negative lookahead instead of lookbehind:

- Find: `((?:cf|vgl)\.)(?:(?!\xA0)\s)+`
- Replace: `$1\xA0`

***Explanation:***

```
(                   # group 1
    (?:cf|vgl)          # non capture group, cf OR vgl
    \.                  # a dot
)                   # end group 1
(?:                 # non capture group
    (?!\xA0)            # negative lookahead, make sure the next char  is not a non-breaking space
    \s                  # any kind of space
)+                  # end group, may appear 1 or more times
```

Comment: @Earendil: You're welcome, glad it helps. Feel free to mark the answer as accepted, [How to accept an answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)

Comment: Thank you @toto, this worked beautifully.

May I ask another question? I hope you can help.

Other strings I want to search/replace have this pattern:

Example 1. 
1 joh 3 
Example 2. 
1 Joh 3,5

In this case too I want to insert \xA0 where absent. To do this, here is what I use:

Find:
([0-9]{1,}+)([^\xA0])([a-z]{1,}+)([^\xA0])([0-9]{1,})(\,)*([\s]*)([0-9]{1,})*
Replace:
$1 $3 $5$6$8

This works but it also finds strings with 2 \xA0

How do I search exclusively for:

1\xa0Joh\s3
1\sJoh\xa03
1\xa0Joh\s3,6
1\sJoh\xa03,6

and not: 

1\xa0Joh\xa03
1\xa0Joh\xa03,6

Comment: @Earendil: Don't ask question in comments, it is unreadable. Please, ask a new question with sample text and expected result and I'll be glad to answer it (if I can!)

Comment: Thank you Toto! Yes, I hope you can solve the next one.